# Adjective: Use of than in degree

Tags: adjective-degrees

I was going through error detection exercise. I came across a question -

> He is the oldest than other player in the team

My book says, *than* is superfluous. 
Anyone tell me which rule follow here and why *than* is superfluous.

Comment: If that actually is the sentence used in the book, you should get rid of the book. It has multiple errors that either using or omitting *than* will not fix.

Comment: Pradeep, as Jason said, you should not read that book. It seems like it is not a properly edited book. What is the name of the book by the way?

Comment: @Man_From_India SP Bakshi english for ssc

Comment: @Pradeep I have heard about this book from elsewhere too. And it seems like it is not particularly in here that the error took place, the errors are scattered throughout the book. So my opinion is please stay away from this book.

Answer (score 2):

That sentence is wrong. It could be:

> He is the oldest player in the team.

or

> He is older than the other players in the team.